# Change datatype of column to uniqueidentifier from bigint

Tags: sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I want to change the datatype of a column in a table in sql server. I used the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbltest  
ALTER COLUMN ID uniqueidentifier
```

But it throws the error

> Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot convert from an integer to a `uniqueidentifier`. But you can do it like this.

1. First delete old data from the table.
2. Alter the column to some text-format (such as `VARCHAR(200)`).

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE dbo.tbltest  
   ALTER COLUMN ID VARCHAR(200)
   ```
3. Now again

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.tbltest  
   ALTER COLUMN ID uniqueidentifier
   ```

To be clear, you can't convert a column from numeric to `uniqueidentifier` directly, but you can convert `numeric` to `varchar` to `uniqueidentifier`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the column first (possibly with a default or nullable so that the column can be successfully added to rows with existing data), update it to the values you want or need, change any keys (if it is a primary key change it to the new column and then also change any foreign keys to this table), then remove the old column and alter the new column as necessary (e.g. setting identity seed, removing nullable, etc.).

Comment: I see. In that case you may also be able to alter it to `binary(16)` first and then to `bigint` - not tested but as far as I remember SQL Server allows this as long as no data is being truncated in the process.

Answer (score 3):

**Note to people using Entity Framework:**
Obviously, if you have a large database with complex relationships, dropping all relationships and ID columns, and re-adding them is a huge ordeal.

It's *much* easier to update the generated model (.edmx).
Yes, Visual Studio allows you to update the data type without complaining. In fact, when you save the .edmx file, the relationships will be validated; any fields that you may have missed will show up as errors.

After you're finished, you can regenerate the database from the model. Boom, done.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other answers that state that this can't be done without dropping data. In fact @Lucero has already eluded to the correct way to do this in his comment.

You most certainly can convert a BigInt to a UniqueIdentifier (and back again if you wish.) You DO NOT need to drop the table, truncate the data, or do anything more radical then run a few commands. It takes two steps:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbltest ALTER COLUMN [ID] VARBINARY(8)
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbltest ALTER COLUMN [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
```

Now keep in mind that only the front half of the generated GUID will be non-zero values because a BitInt value is 8 bytes and a UniqueIdentifier is 16 bytes, so you'll end up with Guid's that look like:

> E38E4965-8DFC-4FF3-0000-000000000000

Answer (score 0):

If Singh's answer is not working then you probably have to drop the the table and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Change you column datatype to :

1. Nvarchar() or varchar()
2. Your column must be Null because UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is unique and has a clean format or standard ,like PK generated automticly by SGBD
   this an example to create and generate UNIQUEIDENTIFIER :

> Blockquote

```
` ALTER TABLE File ADD [Guid_1] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() NOT NULL
  UPDATE File SET [GUID] = [GUID_1]
  ALTER TABLE File DROP CONSTRAINT DF__File_Last__Guid___69727791
  ALTER TABLE File DROP COLUMN [GUID_1];
  ALTER table File ALTER COLUMN [GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL;
 `
```