# How to change data type from date to int in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    s_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    sname nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    address nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    birthyear date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Student PRIMARY KEY (s_id)
);
```

Now I want to change data type of column `birthyear` from `date` to `integer`.

I followed tutorial of w3school.com :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE Student 
ALTER COLUMN birthyear int
```

But it throws an error

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Can you people help me? Please.

Thank you!

Comment: did you delete all the old data from the table?

Comment: Please can you advise if you require the date as the count in days from January 1, 1 AD or if you want the date to be expressed as an integer such as ISO yyyymmdd format e.g. 20150507.

Comment: @corky_bantam : I use DATE type but i can't insert into this column with value such as 1978, 1980, 1985. I mean that i just used to 4 numbers for birth year . :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this directly - a `DATE` isn't an `INT` - how should SQL Server convert a date like `2015-05-07` into an `INT` ??

You have basically two options:

**Option #1**: rename the current column `birthyear` to `birthdate` and add a computed column `birthyear` that gives you the year only of that date:

```
-- rename "birthyear" to "birthdate"
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Student.Birthyear' , 'BirthDate', 'COLUMN'

-- add new computed column "birthyear"
ALTER TABLE dbo.Student 
   ADD BirthYear AS YEAR(birthdate) PERSISTED
```

**Option #2**: create new column, put the year of your date into that column, drop old column, rename new column to old name

```
-- add new  column "newbirthyear"
ALTER TABLE dbo.Student 
   ADD NewBirthYear INT 

-- update table, extract YEAR(birthyear) into new column
UPDATE dbo.Student
SET NewBirthYear = YEAR(birthyear)

-- drop old column
ALTER TABLE dbo.Student
DROP COLUMN birthyear

-- rename new column back to old column name
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Student.NewBirthyear' , 'BirthYear', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 18):

When column is empty (all NULLs) you can make transitional step by using varchar conversion.
Direct conversion is not possible, but this should work:
**date -> varchar -> int**

```
ALTER TABLE Student ALTER COLUMN birthyear varchar(200);
ALTER TABLE Student ALTER COLUMN birthyear int;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115463/1925568).