# How to change datatype of foreign key in EF code-first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I have two models

```
public class ContractType
{
    public Guid ContractTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class JobPost : BasePost
{
    public ContractType ContractType { get; set; }
    public Guid ContractTypeId { get; set; }    
}
```

As you can see `ContractTypeId` is a foreign key in `JobPost` table.

Then, I updated them to the database with code-first.

But I just decided to have `int` type for `ContractTypeId` instead of `Guid`. So I just changed the data type of `ContractTypeId` to `int` and added migration. There was no data for two both tables. This is what I get

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes");
        DropIndex("dbo.JobPosts", new[] { "ContractTypeId" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes");
        AlterColumn("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AlterColumn("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes");
        DropIndex("dbo.JobPosts", new[] { "ContractTypeId" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes");
        AlterColumn("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
```

But, when I update database with `update-database`, I get an error:

> Error Number:206,State:2,Class:16
>   Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

I know since I have not yet populated any data for the tables, I can simply remove and recreate the models and update them.

But I want to know How i can solve this or how I can change the datatype of `ContractTypeId`.

Thanks guys

Comment: Added my answer I tested in on my local EF 6.1.3 it worked after few retries :) Nice question by the way helpful for those who like to do it in EF code first .

Comment: @YashveerSingh Thanks for the response, I will try it tonight!!

Comment: ok no problem I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

here you go . because you have no data which is good :) The tricky is to first delete column and add them again .Becuase we cannot change the uniquiueidentitfier to int directly read few post where that was mentioned 
 [Change datatype of column to uniqueidentifier from bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115311/change-datatype-of-column-to-uniqueidentifier-from-bigint)  . So accordingly I adopted the migration :) Might be helpfull for other who like to do it from EF code first.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes");
        DropIndex("dbo.JobPosts", new[] { "ContractTypeId" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes");


        -- below line added manaully
        DropColumn("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId");
        -- below line added manaully
        AddColumn("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));

        -- below line added manaully
        DropColumn("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId");

        -- below line added manaully
        AddColumn("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));


        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobPosts", "ContractTypeId", "dbo.ContractTypes", "ContractTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
```